# Powerpoint Protected Mode with Disabled Ribbon - Automated in Delphi

Tags: delphi, user-interface, automation, ms-office, powerpoint

I am looking for a way to protect powerpoint presentations via Automation using Delphi.
In Word, I can issue this command:

```
  If (WordDocument.ProtectionType = wdNoProtection)
    Then WordDocument.Protect (3, VarTrue, VarProtectPass);
```

In Excel, I can issue this command:

```
  { If the file was NOT protected, then protect it }
  For SheetIndex := 1 To ExcelWorkbook.Sheets.Count Do Begin

    VarSheet := SheetIndex;

    { Connect to the work sheet }
    ExcelWorksheet.ConnectTo (ExcelWorkbook.Worksheets.Item [VarSheet] As _Worksheet);

    ExcelWorksheet.Protect ()...
```

The problem is that I cannot find a way to do this using the OfficeXP.pas components.  We are running Office 2010 on various systems.  Any ideas?

What I need is to open powerpoint up with the presentation, 
1)  For MenuItem1, Disallow any editting by the user.  Also, disallow them to re-save it somewhere else.
2)  For MenuItem2, Allow the user to edit the presentation.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb230554%28office.12%29.aspx but then also see [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/innovateonoffice/thread/28aff4b7-06f3-46e0-a7d7-495e85bf6bb2)

Comment: What is the PowerPoint action that you wish to automate?

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this would be via an add-in that traps events:

Trap the PresentationBeforeSave event and if need be, cancel the save.

Trap the WindowSelectionChange event, test to see what's selected (it's passed by the event) and in most cases, DE-select the selection.  If the user can't select something, they can't edit/change it.

The event handling routines can be enabled/disabled based on state variables; you might trap the PresentationOpen event, test to see if the new presentation is one of your "protected" ones and if so, set boolIsProtected = True; your other event handlers could test this variable and stop processing the event if False.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked, which was how to do this via Automation using Delphi. :-)